# Clang can't find C++ module with `-fprebuilt-module-path`

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, clang++

I have two files, main.cc and S.cc, in the same directory. S.cc contains a module named `S_mod`. When compiling I get an error about `S_mod` not being found despite using `-fprebuilt-module-path=.`. I've tried creating a separate directory for the *.pcm files but that had no effect.

main.cc:

```
import S_mod;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

S.cc:

```
export module S_mod;

export struct S {
    int x, y;
};
```

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. --precompile -x c++-module S.cc -o S.pcm
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. -c S.pcm -o S.o
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. S.o main.cc -o test
main.cc:3:8: fatal error: module 'S_mod' not found
import S_mod;
~~~~~~~^~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the following, I added some output to your `main.cc` so it looks like this, to demonstrate it's all working.

```
import S_mod;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    S s = { 1, 2 };
    std::cout << s.x << " " << s.y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You need to make sure all the names of your module artifacts are correct. For you, `main.cc` expects to find `S_mod`, and by default, Clang expects to find something named `S_mod.pcm` for compilation.

So, for example, this set of commands would work correctly because you'd be outputting a `.pcm` file with the same name as the module you're trying to import.

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts --precompile -x c++-module S.cc -o S_mod.pcm
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c S_mod.pcm -o S_mod.o -fprebuilt-module-path=.
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. main.cc -o test
./test
1 2
```

Alternatively, you can specify `-fmodule-file` which allows you to specify the mapping of `module_name=module_file`.

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts --precompile -x c++-module S.cc -o S.pcm
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c S.pcm -o S.o

# Notice that we map S_mod=S.pcm - you could just say S.pcm but 
# then clang will always load the module file regardless of whether
# or not it needs to
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. -fmodule-file="S_mod=S.pcm" main.cc -o test
./test
1 2
```